# Typescript "spread" interface in function call

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I want to type some inputs of a function using an interface, is there a way to "spread" the interface to avoid passing an object in the function call?

```js
interface GreetInputs {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const greet = ({ name, age }: GreetInputs) => {
    return `Hello ${name}, you are ${age} years old!`;
};

// this is annoying to pass as object
greet({name: 'Jack', age: 25})


const greet2 = (name: string, age: number) => {
    return `Hello ${name}, you are ${age} years old!`;
};

// this is nicer to call but inputs are not typed with GreetInputs 
greet2('Jack', 25)
```

Ideally I would have something like

```js
const greet3 = (...args: GreetInputs) => {
    return `Hello ${name}, you are ${age} years old!`;
};

// this is easy to call and inputs are typed with GreetInputs
greet3('Jack', 25)
```

Comment: Object types don't have an observable property ordering; there's no difference between `{a: 0, b: 1}` and `{b: 1, a: 0}`.  So `(...args: GreetInputs) => ...` wouldn't have any way to know whether `name` or `age` would be the first parameter.  See [ms/TS#13298](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298) for a declined request for an observable ordering.

Comment: Even if you could solve that there's no [supported](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) syntax that auto-destructures an object into variable/parameter names without mentioning those names. So this is completely impossible. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: what if I specified the ordering in the function signature?

Comment: Maybe? Without a [mre] of what you're talking about it's hard to be sure. Do you want to [edit] the question to show what that would look like?  (Even so, I suspect the answer will still be "no" or "the boilerplate needed to make it work would almost always be more work than just doing it directly in the first place")

Comment: Like, there's [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9bGMm), but it doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't seem worth it